# Formal definition of limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, definition

The formal definition of limit of a sequence says that  for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a number $M>0$ such that if $n > M$  it is true that $|(a_n) - L| <  ε$

In this particular case I have to demonstrate by the definition that this limit exist:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n^2+4)}{(n-1)(n+2)(n-3)}=0$$
I have made the following reasoning: I have a hypothesis that is "for all $ n> M $" and a thesis that says "it is true that $ | (a_n) - L | <ε$" but contrary to initiate by the hypothesis to arrive to the thesis, I can initiate by the thesis to arrive at the hypothesis if the steps are reversible.

So, the **firts step** would be:
$$\left\lvert\frac{(n^2+4)}{(n-1)(n+2)(n-3)}\right\rvert <\epsilon $$
And try to take out of the absolute value the expression inside it, then isolate 'n' in terms of ε. We call it equation (1)

The **second step** would be:
find a $M>0$, for that reason conveniently we say that $M>$ equation (1)

The **third step** would be:
By the *Archimedean property* we say that there is a $n>$$M>$ equation (1) and then, by the *transitivity of the order relation* we say that $n>$ equation (1)

The **fourth step** would be:
Isolate 'ε' [that is in equation (1)] in terms of 'n'; call it equation (2)

**Final step** would be:
Take in the absolute value in equation (2) and notice that gives us back the next form:
$$\left\lvert\frac{(n^2+4)}{(n-1)(n+2)(n-3)}\right\rvert <\epsilon $$

**The problem is that** is difficult to do the first step because, is hard to  take out of the absolute value the expression inside it. And then isolate 'n' in terms of ε (even for wolfram alpha). I am asking for any help or a solution for this exercise. Thanks in advance

Comment: The limit should be as $n\to\infty$, not $x\to\infty$. I can't edit this though

Comment: Note that for n>4, the expression between  the absolute value  bars is positive. Divide num and den by n^2 and you get $\dfrac{1-\frac{4}{n^2}}{\left( 1-\frac 1n \right) \left(1 - \frac 3n \right)(n+1)}$.

Comment: Sorry but why for $n\ge 4$?

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 4$ we have

$$\frac{n^2+4}{(n-1)(n+2)(n-3)}<\dfrac{n^2+4}{(n+2)^3}<\dfrac{2n^2}{(n+2)^3}<\dfrac{2(n+2)^2}{(n+2)^3}=\dfrac{2}{n+2}.$$ Thus $$\epsilon=\dfrac{2}{n+2}$$ works.

Comment: Can you please tell me what can I do with your result? I do not see a clear step by step after that

Comment: @C.Canelaux, what he means is that that if you take $M \geq \frac{2}{\epsilon} - 2$ such that $M \in \mathbb{N}$ in your definition (notice this is obtained by solving $\epsilon = \frac{2}{ M + 2}$ for $M$, then if $n > M$, you will have the above inequalities, and from that you can conclude what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=l$ if $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-l| \leq \epsilon, \forall n \geq N$

Lets denote your sequence $a_n$

Let $\epsilon >0$.

For $n \geq 4$, by doing some calculations we see that $|a_n| \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$

From the Archimedian propeprty exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon \Rightarrow N> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Take $N=[\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$ where $[.]$ is the integer part of a number and for which we have that $\forall x$ $$[x] \leq x \leq [x]+1$$ $$x-1 \leq [x] \leq x $$

Now notice that  this $N=[\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$ is the minimum natural number with the property that whenever $$n \geq N  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}< \epsilon $$

Also form the definition of limit this $N$ depends on $\epsilon$

Now  can you see now how the finals step goes?

Also your sequence is a little complicated to find such $N$ that depends on $\epsilon$ so we can bound $a_n$ with as simpler sequence $b_n$ which will allow us to prove more easily the existence of such $N$.